# Get Workflow details by instance id

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

I have workflow history oob list which store workflow history data in workflow  history parent instance id, workflow template id, workflow association id, listid.... Fields.

I want to retrieve workflow details like workflow name by workflow instance id which is stored as I mentioned in above SharePoint Online OOB list. How to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common api for workflow instance service.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RetrieveWorkflowInstances() {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var workflowServicesManager = new SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager(context, web);
            //var workflowDeploymentService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowDeploymentService();
            var workflowInstanceService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();

            //6a899d24-4813-4920-9e61-cdaa2cfe1b3a
            var specificInstance = workflowInstanceService.getInstance("6a899d24-4813-4920-9e61-cdaa2cfe1b3a");
            context.load(specificInstance);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
                console.log(specificInstance);
            }, function (sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                });

            // get all instances
            var workflowInstances = workflowInstanceService.enumerateInstancesForListItem("7B96090E-FDAD-4075-B24A-21686AE255B4", 1);
            context.load(workflowInstances);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
                // enumerateDefinition returns ClientCollection object
                var definitionsEnum = workflowInstances.getEnumerator();
                // Going through the definitions
                while (definitionsEnum.moveNext()) {
                    var def = definitionsEnum.get_current();
                    // Displaying information about this definition - DisplayName and Id
                    console.log("id: " + def.get_id() + " Status: " + def.get_status() + " Stage: " + def.get_userStatus());
                }

            }, function (sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="RetrieveWorkflowInstances()" type="button" value="button" />
```

[image]

[workflow instance properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/dn624256%28v%3Doffice.15%29)

Comment: Thanks for response.. Any powershell script solution to get workflow details by workflow instance id? Note: we have workflow instance id, with this id have to get workflow details.